# How can I create an efficient tree farm?

Tags: terraria

I've created a wooden tower with [wood platform bridges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23252/can-meteorites-land-on-wood-platforms) to find floating islands.  As a result, I need a *lot* of wood and my supply is running low.

I had actually planned for this and created a tree farm, but it isn't very productive.  I set it up as follows, which repeats across a leveled "field" wide enough for forty saplings total.  I know the torches aren't necessary — I used them as a ruler when laying everything out and left some in for looks.

[image: tree farm]

Unfortunately, this seems to produce about one tree per game week or less, which is *painfully* slow compared to my needs.  My suspicion is that the tall grass which grows **constantly** is blocking the growth of trees, which I know need some room around them.  I try to "weed" the farm pretty regularly, but grass starts regrowing by the time I get from one end to the other.

[image: tree farm, overgrown]

What can I do differently to make my tree farm more efficient?

Comment: I usually create jungle biomes for wood farms, since they will spawn trees by themselves.

Comment: Take out the torches, and your formation should be all fine :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the Terraria wiki page on [Trees](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tree):

> ### Growing conditions
>
> Planting an acorn in grass will create a Sapling that will eventually
>   grow into a tree of a random size and shape. Saplings can only grow
>   under the following conditions:
>
> 1. A planted acorn can only be planted on a dirt block covered with grass, corrupt grass, crimson grass, hallow grass, a mud block covered
>      with jungle grass, or on snow.
> 2. The acorn requires one space of open ground to either side.
> 3. There must be at least two open tiles between saplings or only one will grow into a tree. This matches the previous rule, i.e. each acorn
>      needs both adjacent tiles free, which means the closest two trees can
>      be is with two tiles between them.
> 4. The acorn requires at least 32 feet (i.e. 16 tiles) of vertical clearance to grow into a tree.
> 5. An acorn will not grow indoors - all background walls or overhanging ledges must be removed, and if you have a ceiling it must
>      be at least 32 feet above the block where the acorn was planted as
>      measured by a Depth Meter (e.g, if you are planting an acorn at 300
>      feet above, there may only be blocks at 332 feet or higher directly
>      above it in order for it to grow into a tree).
> 6. Acorns will not grow in the presence of torches, wood platforms or sunflowers within its 2-block radius.
> 7. Saplings must be off-screen in order to become trees. They will not grow when currently in view, unlike most other plants which can spawn
>      while you watch.
>
> Saplings can be destroyed with a Pickaxe.

So, you can't grow a tree at the edge of a step or cliff, or next to a step or cliff, or at the edge of a patch of grass, even though you can plant acorns there. While trees can, very rarely, grow a distance of three tiles apart (two empty columns between them), they grow much faster at a distance of four tiles apart (with three empty spaces between them). For these reasons, it is recommended to plant acorns every four tiles on a long flat row of surface grass. Tiles more than 14 units above the planted grass do not have any effect on tree growth, so an optimal tree farm can have multiple 15-tile high levels."

You seem to have your acorns spaced correctly, there are no walls, and I assume you have enough head room.  Although it's not explicitly mentioned in the wiki, your torches may be keeping the trees from growing. Try removing them.  At least some of the acorns should grow to full trees in a matter of minutes.

Comment: I pulled the torches and trees started going off like popcorn.  I guess I'll need to rearrange my lighting. ^.^

Comment: Acorns can also be placed on sand to make Palm trees.

Answer (score 4):

Terraria wiki guide on [Gardening](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Gardening)

> By placing a dirt wall inside the layer of grass blocks (not behind the tree, the block below the tree), one can prevent tall grass from spawning, maximizing efficiency. The dirt wall should peek out from behind the grass blocks and be visible behind the tree, but not actually being in the block behind the tree. The dirt wall should be behind every block of grass, not just the one under the tree.

So place one dirt wall behind the grass that the trees are on, so it just barely sticks out, and there will be no tall grass and you'll never have to weed again.

Answer (score 4):

Most answers are literally missing the forest through the trees (by focusing on one and only one solution), and ignoring the *original* problem.

The OP asked *two* questions:

> As a result, I need a lot of wood and my supply is running low.

and steered people towards one solution:

> What can I do differently to make my tree farm more efficient?

Since no one has answered the *original* question -- I'll present the **two** solutions to get a lot of wood:

## The fast way

Ironically, I found the fastest way to get a lot of wood was *not* to have a tree farm at all!  I found it *far* more efficient (**time wise**) to just create a new world, pick a direction say East, and just chop every tree until you hit the ocean. Use the mirror (or Save & Exit then reload the world) and travel the *opposite* direction as a lumberjack. YMMV but on a small world travelling in just one direction netted:

- 1015 Wood
- 627 Rich Mahogany
- 158 Palm wood
- 102 acorns

Travelling in *both* directions netted a grand total of:

- 1459 wood
- 748 Boreal Wood
- 627 Rich Mahogany
- 255 Palm wood
- 26 Ebonwood
- 223 Acorns

And the stats:

- Total wood: 3115 / Total time: 19 mins = **~ 163 wood/min**
- Total platforms: 6230 platforms = **~ 327 platforms/min**

Rinse and Repeat. This should be enough wood to make those extra long sky bridges arenas. The bonus is that you can **save all those acorns** to (*cough*) *seed* your tree farm. :-)

## The slow way

Traditionally, the tree farm is most popular -- partially due to aesthetics -- but it is *dog slow*.

1. First, you have to prepare a flat surface.

   I recommend 1,000 tiles of dirt (optionally also sand if you want/need Palm wood. If you want jungle trees your tree farm needs mud deep Underground)

   - Plant trees with 4 spaces between saplings. This gives 2 block radius on either side of each tree.
   - Use a hammer so you don't have dirt wallpaper behind as this will block the trees from growing.
   - Place torches below ground so as not to impede the growth of the trees
2. Hurry-up-and-wait.

   Maintenance of the tree farm will require you to continually clear all the grass. If you use a hammer and aim in the sky you can clear all the grass and leave the trees & dirt safely alone.

   To speed up growing the tree farm, hole up like a hobbit near the surface, preferably with a lava trap above, and leave the world running over night. In the morning you should have most of the trees growing and you'll have also made a few extra coins.

Once you have a *large* enough tree farm setup it will produce more wood **quantity-wise** in the long run but *setup & maintenance* time is just a huge PITA compared to just clear cutting on a brand new temporary world.

Answer (score 3):

[image: My Tree Farm]

This is my method of handling a tree farm, I space it at every fourth block for planting for aesthetic reasons, and use the torches to help me mark it out.  The spacing from top of ground to bottom platform (used to eliminate vines dropping down) is 18 blocks.  I usually build up 3 or 4 tiers of 81 blocks wide for worlds where I want a wooden housing projects or to use platforms for skyways and "hell-evator up" mechanisms.  My biggest farm was a 3 tier, 401 block wide farm, producing 100 trees per tier, average was about 2400 wood per harvest cycle.

I have made similar farms for Mahogany, but that is a jungle grass planted trough with a half block deep of water, spaced 18 blocks of height per tier.  You don't plant acorns in this method, but it will produce mahogany trees very regularly.  Just be aware that that will create a jungle biome, with all associated mob spawns (hard mode blood moons make this a bad thing), so ideally don't put it too close to your housing.

*(EDIT from 1.3.1:)*  I just discovered that mahogany can be planted now with acorns on jungle covered mud.  Be aware that you do not gain ANY acorns from mahogany farming, but if you have been doing regular wood, boreal wood, or corrupt/crimson wood at all, you should have a few stacks of acorns you can utilize.  For my mahogany farm, I usually combine it with a jungle shrubbery farm for getting nice early fishing bait.  You can also sink the tree platform under a tile of water to prevent the shrubs from spawning. *(End Edit)*

The only mechanism I don't have in this world's tree farm, is my auto-mowing mechanism.  I use a pressure plate activated dart trap set to fly along the ground, and that "mows the verge" along the top of the ground.  Makes mushroom picking fast and grasshopper gathering easy.  WARNING: Birds and Bunnies will be in danger using this method.

Answer (score 1):

It is the weeds. If something is beside the sapling it will Not grow.

Here is a picture of the right side of my tree farm (something like this exists in every world I have played in so far).

[image]

You can weed, plant and harvest the trees from the lower level. Often when I go through and plant my trees and weed them, I will have a tree fully grown by the time I am done, if not two. This has always exceeded my usage of wood, which can be excessive at times.

It seems giving the grass covered dirt two directions to 'sprout' in (up and down as vines) gives the trees a much better chance. I would NOT recommend doing this to your entire 40 tree area (Thats 480 blocks to dig out or so :)). But give it a try on one section and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just know from experience that to plant a tree, these requirements must be met:

1.) There must be nothing nearby(you don't need to babysit the trees all the time, just clear
    the weeds once a game day).
2.) There must be a patches of grass nearby(you don't need to worry about this,since they will
    grow by themselves).
3.) There must be no wall and the trees must not be underground.

I may not be entirely correct and if you still have difficulty growing trees after meeting these requirements, check this out http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Acorn.

Answer (score -1):

I found it effective to make or find a long flat plain then upon it I place i torch after two blocks I place a acorn-tree-then again I went two blocks then a torch then two blocks then a acorn... Ect