# Protecting home and nearest territory from meteor

Tags: terraria

I've managed to build a beautiful big house in Terraria for me and NPCs. Also there is storage area with chests with loot inside in this house.

- How I can protect my house from being destroyed by a meteor?
- Is it good idea to make a horizontal stone wall above house?
- Also, I want to have opportunity to gather meteorite ore after meteor falling. I know that there are issues with bridges in the sky. Because when meteor strikes them, only a small number of meteor blocks are generated :-(

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that they can't land on your house, but I can't find a reference for that

Comment: Points 1 & 2 are sort of the same question: "How do I protect my home from meteors?" but for point 3, see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23252/can-meteorites-land-on-wood-platforms).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [an answer* to a related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23252/can-meteorites-land-on-wood-platforms/23276#23276), it is stated that:

> [A meteor] may not intersect with a Player, an NPC or a Chest.

If your house is only large enough for your NPCs, it's quite likely you're already safe.  If not, as an alternative to making a skybridge barrier, you might instead make an "attic" full of chests.  This will cause the game to look for a different location entirely rather than leave only a thin layer of meteorite, as a skybridge would.

**My understanding is that the rules listed in the linked post were determined by examining the game's code, but it wasn't done by me, so caveat emptor.  ;-)*

Comment: OK, thanks, I understood. So meteor can't fall in region near spawn point.

Comment: What about if you build your settlement away from spawn, and haven't yet built a bed?

Comment: by the way, you can't place all the chests you want, [there is a limit of 1000 storage items in a world](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Storage_item#Notes).

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to protect your house, then build a sky bridge over you house. However, if you want to havest the meteor, I suggest that you create another world just for meteor harvesting. Also, the chance of having a meteor strike your house **should be** very small so there should be not much to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect it fully and harvest it I recommend making a shield 50 blocks or more above your house and fill it with unwanted blocks. If you have the means to get up there such as jetboots and a grappling hook, once the meteorite falls go up with a pickaxe (Gold or better) and then harvest and repeat.